# Xamarin Gridview Height Skew Scrollview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a gridview in my app and i'm able to increase its height dynamically. But my issue is that every time i increase the height, the scrollbar scrolls to the center of the page. What could cause this issue ? Here is my code below :

**Axml :**

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView

      android:layout_width="match_parent"

      android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

                   android:layout_width="match_parent"

                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                   android:orientation="vertical"

                   android:gravity="center"

                   android:background="#e1effa">
               <GridView

                   android:id="@+id/gvPhones"

                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"

                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                   android:gravity="center"

                   android:verticalSpacing="5dp"

                   android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"

                   android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

       </LinearLayout>


 </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**Cs :**

```
  _mySimpleItemLoader = new LoadRecords();
  _mySimpleItemLoader.LoadMoreItems();

  gvPhone = FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.gvPhones);
   _gridviewAdapter = new PhonesAdapter(this, _mySimpleItemLoader, this);
   gvPhone.Adapter = _gridviewAdapter;
   gvPhone.LayoutParameters.Height = 777 * gvPhone.Count;
```

Comment: Try setting the following property in your LinearLayout - `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`.

Comment: Thank you Cole. This tag solved my problem.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Yes i solved my problem.

Comment: Absolutely. I did, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But my issue is that every time i increase the height, the scrollbar scrolls to the center of the page.

When you  open an `Activity`, some control needs to take focus. But in your `.axml` layout there's no designated control to take focus, the system chooses the first eligible control that wants focus.

When you set the `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` property in your `LinearLayout`,  your `LinearLayout` will be focused on start and your `NestedScrollView` won't scroll to the center of the page.